# Node not responding on port 5000 from different subnet

Tags: networking, centos, node.js

So I've got 2 subnets, Load balancer and backends.

BE1 is running a node server, as we're trying to get sockets working:

BE1 can request localhost:5000/test
BE2 can request BE1:5000/test

LB1 can request BE1:80
LB1 -cannot- request BE1:5000/test

`[root@lb1 ~]# curl be1:5000/test
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

from any other server I get

`[root@be1 ~]# curl be1:5000/test
Hello world`

Any idea's would be helpful - Just trying to figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a firewall issue on LB1, since all other options are ruled out by your setting, where:

1. BE2 can connect to BE1:5000 (this rules out option that BE1:5000 is unreachable to everyone)
2. LB1 can connect to BE1:80 (this rules out option that BE1 is unreachable to LB1)
3. curl gives `(7) couldn't connect to host error` when connecting to port 5000 (this rules out option that firewall is running on BE1 itself)

So the solution would be flushing iptables on LB1/adding rules for any firewalls that may be running between two networks (traceroute to BE1 from LB1 should give you a list).

Comment: It's a web server - so I was just highlighting the fact that normal HTTP traffic -can- get through via port 80.

Comment: Also - you were right. I spoke with our hosting company. Two LB's are in a different subnet to the two BE's, so they go through the firewall.Thanks for the help! :)